# AMQP error while attempting pushRaw: Undefined index: name

Tags: php, laravel, rabbitmq, queue, jobs

I am upgrading Laravel from `5.4.*` to `5.5.0`. RabbitMQ worked absolutely fine in `5.4` but now when I try to run functionality that uses queues, it shows the following error in the logs:

> AMQP error while attempting pushRaw: Undefined index: name

There is no other information in the logs. Here is my `.env`:

```
RABBITMQ_HOST=localhost
RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
RABBITMQ_VHOST=/
RABBITMQ_LOGIN=test
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=test
RABBITMQ_QUEUE=reporting
RABBITMQ_JOB_QUEUE=dev
```

Here is the config in my `queue.php`:

```
'worker' => [
    'driver' => 'rabbitmq',
    'factory_class' => Enqueue\AmqpLib\AmqpConnectionFactory::class,
    'host' => env('RABBITMQ_HOST'),
    'port' => env('RABBITMQ_PORT'),
    'vhost' => env('RABBITMQ_VHOST'),
    'login' => env('RABBITMQ_LOGIN'),
    'password' => env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD'),
    'queue' => env('RABBITMQ_JOB_QUEUE'),

    'options' => [
        'exchange' => [
            'name' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME', null),
            /*
            * Determine if exchange should be created if it does not exist.
            */
            'declare' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_DECLARE', true),
            /*
            * Read more about possible values at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html
            */
            'type' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_TYPE', \Interop\Amqp\AmqpTopic::TYPE_DIRECT),
            'passive' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_PASSIVE', false),
            'durable' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_DURABLE', true),
            'auto_delete' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_AUTODELETE', false),
            'arguments' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_ARGUMENTS'),
        ],
        'queue' => [
            /*
            * Determine if queue should be created if it does not exist.
            */
            'declare' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DECLARE', true),
            /*
            * Determine if queue should be binded to the exchange created.
            */
            'bind' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DECLARE_BIND', true),
            /*
            * Read more about possible values at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html
            */
            'passive' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_PASSIVE', false),
            'durable' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DURABLE', true),
            'exclusive' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_EXCLUSIVE', false),
            'auto_delete' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_AUTODELETE', false),
            'arguments' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_ARGUMENTS'),
        ],
    ],
],
```

This is the version of `RabbitMQ` in `composer.json`:

```
"vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq": "6.0.0",
```

My Laravel version is `5.5.0`. The task I am trying to push into queue is:

```
\Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new MailPriceRequest($priceRequests));
```

What is going wrong here? Any help?

**EDIT:**

Here is the `MailPriceRequest` class:

```
class MailPriceRequest extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    public $title;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    public $items;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $groupedPriceRequests = [];

    /**
     * @var
     */
    public $grouped;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $groupName = '';

    /**
     * @var
     */
    public $emailSubject;

    /**
     * MailPriceRequest constructor.
     * @param $transportOrders
     */
    public function __construct($priceRequests)
    {
        $this->items = $priceRequests;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $this->setPriceRequests();
        $this->setTitle();
        $this->setGrouped();
        $this->setSubject();
        return $this->subject($this->emailSubject)->view('emails.price-requests.overview');
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSubject()
    {
        $this->emailSubject = $this->getOrderNumber();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setGrouped()
    {
        $this->grouped = $this->groupedPriceRequests;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setTitle()
    {
        $this->title = 'title';

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPriceRequests()
    {
        $this->groupByCarrier();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function groupByCarrier()
    {
        $transformer = \App::make(PriceRequestMailTransformer::class);
        foreach ($this->items as $priceRequest) {
            if (!array_key_exists($priceRequest->carrier_name, $this->groupedPriceRequests)) {
                $this->groupedPriceRequests[$priceRequest->carrier_name] = [
                    'price_requests' => []
                ];
            }
            $transformed = $transformer->transform($priceRequest);

            $this->groupedPriceRequests[$priceRequest->carrier_name]['price_requests'][] = $transformed;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    private function getOrderNumber()
    {
        if (count($this->items) > 1) {
            return ' - ' . $this->items->first()->order_number . ' - and more references';
        }

        if (count($this->items) == 1) {
            return ' - ' . $this->items->first()->order_number;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the  code  `MailMailPriceRequest` class?

Comment: @Dmitry I have updated the question with `MailPriceRequest` class.

Comment: did you upgrade php too ? or was it already at 7.*

Comment: `'name' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME', null),`
If I remember correctly, specifying exchange names are generally a required field. Otherwise an empty string.\

Comment: @shinjw that didn't make any difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

Added this line in the `[options][queue]` array:

```
'name' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME', env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Document about [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html) configuration and In Laravel .env set as following;

```
RABBITMQ_HOST=localhost
RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
RABBITMQ_VHOST=/
RABBITMQ_LOGIN=test
RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=test
RABBITMQ_QUEUE=reporting
RABBITMQ_JOB_QUEUE=dev
# Exchange name is a required field. 
RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME=yourexchangename
```

In your queue.php file set the exchange name env variable.

```
'worker' => [
    'driver' => 'rabbitmq',
    'factory_class' => Enqueue\AmqpLib\AmqpConnectionFactory::class,
    'host' => env('RABBITMQ_HOST'),
    'port' => env('RABBITMQ_PORT'),
    'vhost' => env('RABBITMQ_VHOST'),
    'login' => env('RABBITMQ_LOGIN'),
    'password' => env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD'),
    'queue' => env('RABBITMQ_JOB_QUEUE'),

    'options' => [
        'exchange' => [
            // Exchange name is a required field. 
            'name' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME', null),
            /*
            * Determine if exchange should be created if it does not exist.
            */
            'declare' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_DECLARE', true),
            /*
            * Read more about possible values at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html
            */
            'type' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_TYPE', \Interop\Amqp\AmqpTopic::TYPE_DIRECT),
            'passive' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_PASSIVE', false),
            'durable' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_DURABLE', true),
            'auto_delete' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_AUTODELETE', false),
            'arguments' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_ARGUMENTS'),
        ],
        'queue' => [
            'name' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME', env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE')),
            /*
            * Determine if queue should be created if it does not exist.
            */
            'declare' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DECLARE', true),
            /*
            * Determine if queue should be binded to the exchange created.
            */
            'bind' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DECLARE_BIND', true),
            /*
            * Read more about possible values at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html
            */
            'passive' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_PASSIVE', false),
            'durable' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DURABLE', true),
            'exclusive' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_EXCLUSIVE', false),
            'auto_delete' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_AUTODELETE', false),
            'arguments' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_ARGUMENTS'),
        ],
    ],
],
```

Another example of defining rabbitmq driver for Laravel

```
'connections' => [
    // ...
    'rabbitmq' => [

        'driver' => 'rabbitmq',

        /*
         * Set to "horizon" if you wish to use Laravel Horizon.
         */
        'worker' => env('RABBITMQ_WORKER', 'default'),

        'dsn' => env('RABBITMQ_DSN', null),

        /*
         * Could be one a class that implements \Interop\Amqp\AmqpConnectionFactory for example:
         *  - \EnqueueAmqpExt\AmqpConnectionFactory if you install enqueue/amqp-ext
         *  - \EnqueueAmqpLib\AmqpConnectionFactory if you install enqueue/amqp-lib
         *  - \EnqueueAmqpBunny\AmqpConnectionFactory if you install enqueue/amqp-bunny
         */

        'factory_class' => Enqueue\AmqpLib\AmqpConnectionFactory::class,

        'host' => env('RABBITMQ_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('RABBITMQ_PORT', 5672),

        'vhost' => env('RABBITMQ_VHOST', '/'),
        'login' => env('RABBITMQ_LOGIN', 'guest'),
        'password' => env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD', 'guest'),

        'queue' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE', 'default'),

        'options' => [

            'exchange' => [

                'name' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME'),

                /*
                 * Determine if exchange should be created if it does not exist.
                 */

                'declare' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_DECLARE', true),

                /*
                 * Read more about possible values at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html
                 */

                'type' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_TYPE', \Interop\Amqp\AmqpTopic::TYPE_DIRECT),
                'passive' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_PASSIVE', false),
                'durable' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_DURABLE', true),
                'auto_delete' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_AUTODELETE', false),
                'arguments' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_ARGUMENTS'),
            ],

            'queue' => [

                /*
                 * Determine if queue should be created if it does not exist.
                 */

                'declare' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DECLARE', true),

                /*
                 * Determine if queue should be binded to the exchange created.
                 */

                'bind' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DECLARE_BIND', true),

                /*
                 * Read more about possible values at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html
                 */

                'passive' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_PASSIVE', false),
                'durable' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DURABLE', true),
                'exclusive' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_EXCLUSIVE', false),
                'auto_delete' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_AUTODELETE', false),
                'arguments' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_ARGUMENTS'),
            ],
        ],

        /*
         * Determine the number of seconds to sleep if there's an error communicating with rabbitmq
         * If set to false, it'll throw an exception rather than doing the sleep for X seconds.
         */

        'sleep_on_error' => env('RABBITMQ_ERROR_SLEEP', 5),

        /*
         * Optional SSL params if an SSL connection is used
         * Using an SSL connection will also require to configure your RabbitMQ to enable SSL. More details can be founds here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html
         */

        'ssl_params' => [
            'ssl_on' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL', false),
            'cafile' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_CAFILE', null),
            'local_cert' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_LOCALCERT', null),
            'local_key' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_LOCALKEY', null),
            'verify_peer' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_VERIFY_PEER', true),
            'passphrase' => env('RABBITMQ_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),
        ],   

    ],
    // ...    
],
```